# How to write an interface to lichess for a millenium board using chesslink?

Tags: programming, computer-chess, lichess

I am aware of the [python chess](https://pypi.org/project/python-chess/) and chesslink [mchess](https://domschl.github.io/python-mchess/doc/build/html/index.html) work but would like to attempt to interface it with [lichess.org](https://github.com/lichess-org/api).  My purpose would be to play others on lichess using my Millenium board. 
 The API's I've found for lichess seem to be for a chess engine interface rather than external hardware.  Any guidelines on where to find other similar work (like how DGT may do it)?

Answer (score 1):

As you've seen, the [Lichess API](https://lichess.org/api) only allows bots to use the API functions that make moves in an ongoing game.  As far as I can tell, this is intentional; the API requires that anything that can generate moves in a game by some means other than human interaction on the Lichess site must be flagged as a bot.

Which means (again, as far as I can tell...), the only way to do what you want to do would be to create some kind of intermediary between the e-board and Lichess that actually mimics the actions a human would take during a game (such as simulating mouse clicking and movement on a game's web page).

I personally would not know where to start if I were trying to do this, and I also don't know if doing something like this would trip Lichess's anti-cheating detection in any way.  But it appears that this is what you'd have to do in order to play on Lichess using an e-board.